How to verify a crystal is damaged?
I need to check in one of designs to see if my crystal (8MHz) is working or not, the schematic is as follows:

When I check the USSXOUT pin I see the following signals:

Here I see almost 1 second between pulses, but when when I zoom in, inside each pulse there are two pules as follows (period= 19.6ms):

Can we confirm that this crystal is not functioning as it should be (8MHz)?

Careful: The probe likely disturbed that very sensitive circuit. Usually you cannot measure the crystal pins directly. Use an indirect method on whatever that crystal is connected to..

@urbo J would you please let me know what can be an indirect method?

@Andromeda what is your crystal connected to?

I'm betting it's a TI MSP430FR6043. Those can use a 4 to 8 MHz crystal or ceramic resonator and I believe there are some settings in it you have to set depending on which you use and what frequency.

As @GodJihyo has mentioned, it is more common that ceramic resonators include integrated capacitors. Are you certain that Y3 is an 8 MHz crystal? Please add the crystal part # and associated active oscillator (USSX_out, USSX_in)

You can confirm something is not functioning, and it may be your hardware or software, and it is weird that you talk about a crystal but the schematics does not show a crystal and why there are two sets of caps, both internal and external? The Y3 itself might be just fine.

@vicatcu it is connected to a MCU, MSP430FR6046.

@glen_geek, yes exactly, I'm using their untouched firmware form TI website, so maybe at this point we should not be worry about the MCU configuration?! or you think we need to check it?

@glen_geek Yes it is a crystal :https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/abracon-llc/AWSCR-8-00CV-T/2001371, the part number: AWSCR-8.00CV-T

@Justme The crystal part number is: AWSCR-8.00CV-T, Digikey link: https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/abracon-llc/AWSCR-8-00CV-T/2001371

@Justme it seems based on the datasheet (https://www.digikey.nl/nl/products/detail/abracon-llc/AWSCR-8-00CV-T/2001371), the capacitor and resistor value of the crystal is not correct, am I right?

@Andromeda The page you link to literally says it's a ceramic resonator. It is not a crystal.

This pattern could be normal if this is part of a low-power device designed to conserve the battery - the microcontroller could be programmed to shut down whenever it isn't needed to run. This is a normal way to program microcontrollers when you need to conserve battery power. The µC may be programmed to wake up every one second. Two bursts with a gap may indicate that the µC changes to a different clock speed shortly after it wakes up.

@Andromeda Could you add the link to the datasheet to your question?

@StarCatStarCathttps://abracon.com/Resonators/AWSCR_CV.pdf

The page you link to literally says it's a ceramic resonator. It is not a crystal.
Please read the data sheet.
It is ceramic resonator with built-in capacitors. Which matches your schematic symbol.
Which means, the extra capacitors are just excess load which are not needed and should be removed. That may make it work.
However, if you need the precision of a crystal, you can't use the resonator even if it will oscillate.
The ceramic resonator is only 0.4% tolerance, 4000 PPM, while crystals are much less than 100 PPM and depending on what you use the frequency for, you may need 50 PPM or less.

thanks for the nice answer, in the datasheet i see there is a section for choosing the correct value of the external capacitors and resistor, you mentioned it is not necessary to have these components?

@Andromeda First of all, I don't know what data sheet you are talking about, but it is likely you are reading MCU section about how to calculate the capacitors for a crystal, and you do not have a crystal, and even if you mistook the ceramic resonator for a crystal, your ceramic resonator data sheet does not have the value required to calculate capacitor values, simply because the ceramic resonator comes with built-in capacitors so you don't need to calculate a value for them. Now, it remains unclear if your MCU and the external circuitry  is in any way compatible with that ceramic resonator.

yes I fully agree that the capacitors should be removed. What is the reason of using R15(22 Ohm), do we need it at all? and why? based on the datasheet: https://abracon.com/Resonators/AWSCR_CV.pdf it is mentioned a 1Mohm resistor should be used in parallel? right?

@Andromeda Any resistors or capacitors depend on which exact crystal with some parameters you intend to connect to which exact oscillation circuit, which in your case is the MCU. I don't know why your schematics have a 22 ohm resistor and should it be 0R or maybe 220R, or if your MCU needs a 1Mohm resistor in parallel or not. You can read your MCU data sheet to know what kind of a crystal to connect and how. The crystal data sheet just shows an example of where they connected it and how to test the parameters.
